How can I have multiple videos play on one page?
Having this code only once on the page works perfectly but using it several times for multiple videps has all the videos frozen.
How can I have all of them play on one page?
<video id="video1" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay loop>
  <source src="videos/Utopia-Pt1-Intro.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
 
  Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>

Does adding an id help?
I don't want to use Vimeo or Youtube embeds.

Browsers support multiple videos playing back no problem.  What browser are you using where this isn't working?  Mobile Safari?  Have you tried playing the video as inline or muted?

No, adding id does not solve the current problem. It is because browsers do not allow multiple video playback to prevent sound mixing. However, if you want to play all the videos simultaneously, you can add the mute attribute to the videos.

To resolve the issue with multiple videos freezing on the same page, ensure that each video element has a unique ID. Additionally, adding the muted attribute to each video will allow them to autoplay without being blocked by the browser. Here’s an example of how you can set it up:
<video id="video1" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="videos/Utopia-Pt1-Intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>

<video id="video2" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="videos/Another-Video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>

